# Amazon CLI won't allow me to list objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy contents of an S3 bucket to another bucket on another account, and I wanted to use the CLI to do this. So I set up a bucket policy on the source bucket, allowing a IAM user in the destination account to perform all S3 actions, but it keeps complaining that the ListObjects operation is denied.

I've tried Google, but I can't tell what would be the problem with my policy compared to the solutions I find. Even if I make the source bucket public (and can list it in a browser), it still gives me access denied.

What to do, what to do? Here's my bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/USER"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::SOURCE",
            "arn:aws:s3:::SOURCE/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Your user also needs permission from its own account to reach across to another account's resources.

Answer (score 2):

Please try using below policy,

```js
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1357935677554",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CrossAccountS3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can read the full steps [here](https://www.slashroot.in/how-copy-files-one-s3-bucket-another-s3-bucket-another-account)

Another read [here](http://blog.vizuri.com/how-to-copy/move-objects-from-one-s3-bucket-to-another-between-aws-accounts)